# Portable word macro

Tags: vba, installation, ms-word

I have a set of word macros which I need to share it with my friends. I want to make the job easy for them such that I share them an installable which they will install and all my macros will be automatically added in their PC's MS word s/w (If possible in the MS word ribbon as a shortcut). Is this possible? If yes, please let me know.

Thanks
Bala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible? If yes, please let me know.

Yes, this is possible.

Not using the ribbon, you can save the macros to a DOT template file and distribute that, or to the default Normal.dot file.

Using the ribbon is more advanced: you would need to create an Add-in and hook the macros to the Add-in's Ribbon UI XML.  There is an excellent tutorial/example here:

http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html

Also see Microsoft's documentation/example, here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can play with the word ribbons using the links u provided. But can you please let me know how do I save the macros in a file(a DOT file)? This may be a silly que, but your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take the file you have and using File | Save As select the file type as `Word Template (*.dotx)`. Alternatively, copy and paste the macros from your file in to an existing template like your Normal.dotx.